# C++ yard.h header getting acreage programmatically

Tags: c++, oop

I am relatively new to C++ and it is essentially just a filler class for my college. I am stuck on this yard program. I need to create a header with the requirements below:

following 5 public functions in the Yard class:
`getWidth()`, `setWidth()`, `getLength()`, `setLength()`, and `getAcres()`

Validate the width and length to ensure they are not negative

FYI: There are 43560 square feet in an acre.

NOTE: I have yet to learn anything about headers , classes, objects.

here is the premade code given to me from teacher:

```
// Yard class 

class Yard 
{ 
private:
    double width, length; // Feet

public:
};

// C++ Classes end with a semicolon!

//Program requirements:
//⦁ Create the following 5 public functions in the Yard class://
//⦁ getWidth(), setWidth(), getLength(), setLength(), and getAcres() 
//⦁ The main() driver code is already setup to use these 5 functions
//⦁ Validate the width and length to ensure they are not negative
//⦁ FYI: There are 43560 square feet in an acre
```

here is the code the teacher has set me up in main.cpp:

```
/*oOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOo/
/O::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::O/
/o:::::::::::Programmer: Tristan Moore::::::::::::o/
/:::::::::::::::::Date: 02/07/2021::::::::::::::::o/
/O::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::O/
/oOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOo*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "yard.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /////////////////////////
    //                     //
    //   MINI PROGRAM #3   //
    //                     //
    /////////////////////////

    Yard yard1, yard2, yard3;
    double length, width;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "INPUTTING WIDTH (FT) AND LENGTH (FT), OUTPUTTING ACRES" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    yard1.setLength(150);
    yard1.setWidth(75);

    yard2.setLength(220);
    yard2.setWidth(200);

    // Input
    cout << "Enter the length of your Yard (ft): ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Enter the width of your Yard (ft): ";
    cin >> width;

    if (length < 0){
        length = 0;
    }

    if (width < 0){
        width = 0;
    }

    //set Width
    //set Length

    cout << endl << fixed << setprecision(2);

    // Output
    cout << "Acres in Yard #1 (" << yard1.getLength() << "ft X " << yard1.getWidth() << "ft): " << yard1.getAcres() << endl;
    cout << "Acres in Yard #2 (" << yard2.getLength() << "ft X " << yard2.getWidth() << "ft): " << yard2.getAcres() << endl;
    cout << "Acres in Yard #3 (" << yard3.getLength() << "ft X " << yard3.getWidth() << "ft): " << yard3.getAcres() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

My question is since I am new to Headers, Classes, And Objects. How do I go about creating a working header that has the above 5 functions?

Comment: if you want an answer, you need a question...what is your question ?

Comment: @Heyji the above post. it returns errors. i am very confused. i am trying to make all the public functions from yard.h work properly in my main.cpp.

Comment: If you could spin through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that would help a lot. Normally, we'd expect to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the exact error messages you're receiving, at a minimum

Comment: But there's also the fact that there's a lot of blatant errors in all of this code. `yard3` never has any values assigned to it, and all user input is completely ignored after validation. In the `Yard` class, there's no reason for `i`, `m`, or `area` members to be public, and also the `width` and `length` members are never used. `getLength` writes to output for some reason, and its math is wrong. And standalone method definitions do not normally belong in headers.

Comment: In the list of not-errors-but-dont-do-it-anyway: don't use `using namespace std`, and also don't use `endl`.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think your comments are better directed at the teacher, not the OP!

Comment: "it is essentially just a filler class for my college ... ". And this is just a filler answer: std::string("").

Comment: sorry fellas i am quite new to this. i just need exactly whats named above. i fix 1 error and get 12 more. my class has yet to even cover headers ,classes,and objects yet. so i am at blank slate. i just need to pass this class.

Comment: @SPADES : you can edit your own question to improve it, instead of addressing our comments in other comments. There you can highlight the first error message and ask for help on how to solve it. But "conversing" using the comments is not the way to go on SO.

Comment: @SPADES : your `getAcres()` function does not look like the others... you might want it to look the same : `Yard::getAcres()`

Comment: @MooingDuck : at that level, I would not pollute the OP with such details. Anything that can simplify things and avoid typos is benefic. He will learn later how to write better code. That's not the point today.

Comment: okay I have made an edit to the code from where I first began. I do not quite know how else to simplify what I am asking.

Comment: @SPADES : why did you removed most of what you have produced. It was good. Just the `getAcres()` wasn't good. Also you should tell us what was the error message in your question. And even better : provides us your test program on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NPcvZ5RZvoitvh8A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's a yard.h that will answer the teacher's brief.

```
class Yard
{
    const double _dSqFtToAcre = 43560;
    
    double _length;
    double _width;
public:
    Yard(const double& length = 0, const double& width = 0)
        :_length(length),_width(width)
    {}

    void setLength(const double& length)
    {
        if (length > 0) _length = length;
    }
    
    double getLength() const
    {
        return _length;
    }   
    
    void setWidth(const double& width)
    {
        if (width > 0) _width = width;
    }

    double getWidth() const
    {
        return _width;
    }

    double getAcres() const
    {
        return (_length * _width) / _dSqFtToAcre;
    }
};
```

And this section in main.cpp. Note the checking that the length or width is greater than zero is handled by the Yard class.

```
// Input
cout << "Enter the length of your Yard (ft): ";
cin >> length;
yard3.setLength(length);

cout << "Enter the width of your Yard (ft): ";
cin >> width;
yard3.setWidth(width);
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. since I have fallen behind(clearly) what would you suggest as a reference to learn the above.

Comment: @SPADES First off, if this answered your question then please click on the tick to signify that. Second, C++ isn't really an "entry-level" language, so your route into C++ will depend on whether you already know another language. I'm afraid I learnt by doing in an IT group 25 years ago: and even now I've fallen behind woefully on developments in the language. I would ask your teacher, as if this has been set as course work, they should be able to point you to a reading list.

Comment: @DS_London: First off, if you consider this a decent question that deserves an answer, then click on the tick as well, to signify that.